# Convert PDF to PNG/JPG , using Wand, breaks in production via Gunicorn, fine on debug server

Tags: django, ubuntu, imagemagick, ghostscript, wand

I am trying to convert a PDF to a JPG/PNG via Wand.

This is the code  (edit)

```
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, "file.pdf"):
    with Image(filename=os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, "file.pdf", resolution=100) as image:
        image.save(filename=os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, "file.jpg")
```

It works perfectly on the local dev server, the dev server on the production server, and also in the manage.py shell (on production server) .

However, when using via my production supervisor/guncicorn setup, I get the following error

```
DelegateError at /finance/api/v1/receipt/
Postscript delegate failed `/webapps/bab/bab/Beenie-Man-1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677
```

This is the startupscript.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="bab"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/bab/bab             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/bab/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=bab                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bab.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=bab.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILEchris@python:/webapps/bab$
```

When I was running the tests on the production server, with both running the full debug server & the shell, it was being run with the correct user account & correct virtualenv (not that it would work at all without that)

Could it be an environment variable issue though? Or some kind of permission thing?

Comment: Don't rely on relative file path names. try constructing an absolute path name based off some anchor. For example, ``os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'filename')``. This way it will work even if the current working directory as set by the WSGI server is not where you expect it to be.

Comment: Ah good point, I'm actually checking the file existence as above(edit) in the real project. I'll double check that stuff now, but I'm pretty sure that it's getting the right path in production.

Comment: Since you are running gunicorn as a specific user, then next make sure that users has access to where the file is.

Comment: When running the dev server, or the shell, both are being done as the same user as the gunicorn user. (via sudo su {user})

Comment: The only other I have seen which causes file access problems is SELinux, but I have never seen that with someone using gunicorn. Usually it only affects Apache as it has a more restrictive profile setup by default in SELinux.